# Fire local notification on particular date every year

Tags: ios

I want to schedule a local notification in ios app such that it fires on 28th june every year. I googled about this but unable to get. How to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `UILocalNotification` You can do it.

try,

```
    UILocalNotification *notif = [[cls alloc] init];       
    NSDateFormatter *df=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];
    notif.fireDate = [df dateFromString:@"28-06-2013"];
    notif.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    notif.alertBody = @"You Reminder";
    notif.alertAction = @"Show";
    notif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
    notif.repeatInterval=NSYearCalendarUnit;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notif];
```

Comment: And if i want to fire that every 12th week, how can it be done?